# Map a Linux VM's block device to its vmdk file on the vmware datastore

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware, block-device

For development and staging purposes, I must frequently create clones of individual virtual harddisks (vmdk container) and move/deploy them into some other system.

While I have been able to hack a working POC, I now need a generic approach which works for a lot of VMs I don't even intent to control. I am having difficulties with the mapping of block devices onto the actual vmdk files on the ESX datastores (there are many virtual HDDs per VM).

This vmdk resolution is intended to be performed on the individual VMs, where I have ssh access to all ESXi hosts and this is also how i create and retrieve the vmdk clones. (Yes, this is very hacky and dangerous.)

Ultimately, for example, I will ask my script `what's the corresponding file of /dev/sdd?` and it should reply `/vmfs/volumes/12345678-12345678-1234-123456789abc/foobar/filenamewithoutsemanticalinformation.vmdk`

How do I determine the real path of the vmdk file that maps to a given block devices inside a VM?

I have an idea around matching SCSI Target IDs from inside the VM with the vHDD entries in the vmx file, but I not know if this is reliable information.

### Update

Having played around for a while, I am fairly certain, that matching SCSI controller and target IDs is reliable and can be controled easily. In this case, reliable means static; the system does not alter IDs and they are exposed to the guest exactly as named and numbered in the vmx file. Using `lsscsi` one can get the controller and target IDs of the block devices. One can then grep for `<controller>:<target>.filename` in the vmx-file and extract the filename from the result.

Finding the correct vmx-file is a new problem. This can be acheived by `find-grep`ing all vmx-files on the datastore for the MAC address of the VM. Not the prettiest approach and not recommened for large installations.

Comment: Yes, the SCSI match is reliable.